# How does jQuery Validation plugin indicates that all fields are valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery form [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). My problem is that I want to use it to check if all fields are valid and then run my custom javascript.

Please see the below example:

```
if(valid){
    //enable save button
    //if user accept terms(by using check the check box)
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your form has the ID `my-form-id`, you would first call:

```
$("#my-form-id").validate();
```

This validates the form. And then you can do:

```
if($("#my-form-id").valid()){
    //enable save button
    //if user accept terms(by using check the check box)
} else {
    return false;
}
```

See full doc here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid

Comment: The `.validate()` method does **not** _"validate the form"_.  The `.validate()` method ***initializes*** the plugin on your form.  Validation is then triggered *automatically* by certain events captured by the plugin.